# want to make search filter using RxSwift in iOS

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I have table view that contains list of books I tried to make searchBar and search by book name

[image]
[image]

> this is HomeViewModel

```
private var homeModelSubject      = PublishSubject<[Book]>()
private var filterModelSubject    = PublishSubject<[Book]>()
private var isTableHidden         = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
var searchValueBehavior           = BehaviorRelay<String>(value: "")

var homeModelObservable: Observable<[Book]> {
    return homeModelSubject
}

var filterModelObservable: Observable<[Book]> {
    return filterModelSubject
}

var isTableHiddenObservable:Observable<Bool> {
    return isTableHidden.asObservable()
}

var serchValueObservable: Observable<String> {
    return searchValueBehavior.asObservable()
}

init() {
    serchValueObservable.subscribe(onNext: { value in
        self.homeModelObservable.map({ $0.filter ({
            if value.isEmpty {return true}
            return ($0.name.lowercased().contains(value.lowercased()))
        })
        }).bind(to: self.filterModelSubject).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
    }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

> this function to make bind to text value

```
func bindToSearchValue() {
    searchController.searchBar.rx.text.orEmpty.throttle(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).distinctUntilChanged()
        .bind(to: homeViewModel.searchValueBehavior).disposed(by: disposeBage)
}
```

> this function to subscribe to response

```
func subscribeToResponse() {
    homeViewModel.filterModelObservable.bind(to: self.tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: HomeTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier, cellType: HomeTableViewCell.self)) { row,books,cell in
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        cell.titleLabel.text           = books.name
        cell.secondaryTitleLabel.text  = books.type
        cell.selectionStyle            = .none
        
        if books.available == true {
            cell.avalibaleOrNotLabel.text = "Avalibale"
            cell.avalibaleOrNotStatus.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            cell.avalibaleOrNotLabel.text = "Not Avalibale"
            cell.avalibaleOrNotStatus.backgroundColor = .gray
        }
        
    }.disposed(by: disposeBage)
}
```

the problem ----> when make search did not filter the cell

Comment: FYI: Subjects should never be declared with a `var` always use `let`.

Comment: Okay, But this is not the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The essence of functional reactive programming is to specify the dynamic behavior of a value completely at the time of declaration.
> -- [Heinrich Apfelmus](https://apfelmus.nfshost.com/blog/2011/03/28-essence-frp.html)

Your view model should look like this:

```
class HomeViewModel {
    let filterModelObservable: Observable<[Book]>
    var searchValueObserver: AnyObserver<String?> { searchValueBehavior.asObserver() }
    var homeModelObservable: Observable<[Book]> { homeModelSubject }
    var isTableHiddenObservable:Observable<Bool> { isTableHidden.asObservable() }
    private let homeModelSubject = PublishSubject<[Book]>()
    private let isTableHidden = BehaviorRelay<Bool>(value: false)
    private let searchValueBehavior = BehaviorSubject<String?>(value: "")

    init() {
        filterModelObservable = Observable.combineLatest(
            searchValueBehavior
                .map { $0 ?? "" }
                .startWith("")
                .throttle(.milliseconds(500), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance),
            homeModelSubject
        )
        .map { searchValue, books in
            searchValue.isEmpty ? books : books.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchValue.lowercased()) }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how the values that `filterModelObservable` will emit are fully specified in the code that creates it.

You shouldn't need so many Subjects:

> Subjects provide a convenient way to poke around Rx, however they are not recommended for day to day use. -- [Intro to Rx](http://introtorx.com)

Also note, there is no disposeBag. You shouldn't need a dispose bag in your view model or you are probably doing something wrong.

You should minimize as much as possible the logic contained in your view controller. It should only contain assignments and binds. So your `bindToSearchBar` should look like this:

```
func bindToSearchValue() {
    searchController.searchBar.rx.text
        .bind(to: homeViewModel.searchValueObserver)
        .disposed(by: disposeBage)
}
```

(You probably want to fix the typo in `disposeBage` as well.)

Comment: I make this when make debug this line ===> searchValue.isEmpty ? books : books.filter { $0.name.lowercased().contains(searchValue.lowercased()) } the compiler does not see it

Comment: Sounds like your `Book.name` is probably an optional String. Fix that.

Comment: the problem now is when open home the tableView do not show list of books until make search...

Comment: I updated the answer to put a `startWith` in the chain.

Comment: same problem .. I update question and put screenshots To make the problem clearer

Comment: I updated the answer. The problem was that your `homeModelSubject` is emitting after the `searchValueBehavior` emitted its first value.